# Linq query - varying datatype on column

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I'm running the query below :-

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
            group data by new
            {
                InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                AccRef = data.Field<double>("SiteRefNum"),
            }
            into g
            select new
            {
                Code = "1",
                InvType = "I",
                Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                ChargeTotal = g.Sum(d => d.field<double>("Charge")
            };
```

Due to the way the data is imported into the datatable (from Excel) sometimes the datatype of AccRef is `double` and sometimes it's `string`. Is there a way to overcome this at runtime, as I'd prefer to not have the user modify the source data in Excel before importing.

Comment: How you can put in DB in one column both `double` and `string` data type?

Comment: I assume that it's always string, isn't it? How are you creating this DataTable?

Comment: could you just change the `AccRef` assignment to `AccRef = data.Field<string>("SiteRefNum")` ?

Comment: You can always treat it as a string and use `Double.TryParse()` to see if it is a valid double value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with objects, so it should work for double and for string:

```
var Values = from data in DtSet.Tables["tblCosts"].AsEnumerable()
             group data by new
             {
                 InvNo = data.Field<double>("InvoiceNo"),
                 AccRef = Convert.ToDouble(data["SiteRefNum"]),
             }
             into g
             select new
             {
                 Code = "1",
                 InvType = "I",
                 Account = g.Key.AccRef,
                 InvNo = g.Key.InvNo,
                 ChargeTotal = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("Charge"))
             };
```

Of course that works only if `SiteRefNum` is actually convertable to a `double`.